# How to give margin top in tailwind css to a image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How to give margin top in tailwind css to a image? i want the logo image show me clearly visible but its not properly seen so how to do that i think if i give margin top to the image it will be clear so how to do that in tailwind css?

[image]
my code

```
 <div className="flex-shrink-0 mr-4">
            {/* Logo */}
             <img src={logo} class="rounded-full -mt-10 md:-mt-16 ml-3 md:ml-0 h-20 w-20 md:h-25 md:w-25 border-[6px] border-white bg-white "/>
          </div>
```

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin

Comment: @
UmairFarooq i have check that can write the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove The `md:-mt-16` & `-mt-10` you are pushing it up with it.

Update:Adding `mt-2`

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div className="flex-shrink-0 mr-4">
  <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg" class="rounded-full ml-3   mt-10 md:ml-0 h-20 w-20 md:h-25 md:w-25 border-[6px] border-white bg-white " />
</div>
```

Comment: its not responsive in phone but

Comment: what happens on the phone?

Comment: its going a little bit top but i want in phone it should be a little bit down

Comment: correct way of adding margin-top is `mt-2` & not `-mt-2` if you add `-` minus it means opposite  `-mt-2` will be equal to `margin-bottom:2;`

Comment: so you can add `mt-2` or more but don't use `-` before mt. i will also add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

update your code to this,

```
  <div className="flex-shrink-0 mr-4">
    <img src={logo} class="rounded-full md:-mt-16 ml-3 md:ml-0 h-20 w-20 md:h-25 md:w-25 border-[6px] border-white bg-white "/>
</div>
```

I removed the `-mt-10` previously in the img tag, which gave it a negative margin and made it not totally visible.

You can check the tailwind documentation for a more comprehensive way of doing things at [tailwind][1]

Also, add the mt-[value] to the img itself.
[1]: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin

Comment: still its same give me a vote i will post image

Comment: check my edited question